# How To Implement IdP Initated SAML for WebForms and Database Authentication

Tags: webforms, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

For the first time I've been tasked with implementing SSO. I'll be implementing as an IdP from my customer facing app (aka CustomerApp) to my parent company's service application (aka ParentApp). CustomerApp User will access the ParentApp by clicking a button link in CustomerApp. CustomerApp also handles the logins via Forms Authentication with database persistence. Thank goodness I found your framework ([ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2)) but I didn't seem to find an example project for .NET WebForms. Yes, it's old. I was planning to just convert the IdPInitiatedController to my project so that I could post the attributes to ParentApp. Or should I be looking at the code in the TestIdPCore project? I'm not sure if I need the whole login/logout stuff. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, yes you only need to focus on the code in the IdPInitiatedController, which show how to construct and post a IdP-Initiated SAML 2.0 Authn Response.

There is not a .NET WebForms sample but it should be possible to convert the code in the [.NET Framework IdPInitiatedController sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/IdPInitiatedController.cs)  https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/Controllers/IdPInitiatedController.cs